# Ati weird screen flickering in Ubuntu MATE 15.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, mate

I have a hard drive with Ubuntu MATE 15.10 that I just went to the trouble of making it bootable on multiple devices-a brand new lenovo desktop with an AMD A6 with Radeon R4 graphics, and a decade old lenovo x60s with an Intel Core 2 Duo and a GMA 950. In making it work for the old lenovo, I appear to have screwed up the new one's graphical session, with all kinds of weird graphical glitches, the login screen being a black screen, the desktop being striped strangely, the CRTL-ALT-F1 command line not appearing, and much more after removing the proprietary fglrx. Please help me, I really need both to work with some decency.